# Publishing a Different Version of CSS to Production

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2012, transform, publishing

How can you publish different versions of a CSS file for different environments in visual studio 2012?  I have a CSS file that uses local URLs for development, but a CDN for production.  I would like to transform these like I can with web.config when publishing to different environments.

I am sure this has been answered but I can't find it.